# How to modify IOptions before injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm using .NET 7 Preview and I am storing a secret as an environment variable and trying to assign it to a class I'm injecting with `IOptions`.

I have my other, non-secret parameters stored in `appsettings.json`:

```
"MyServerName": {
    "EnvironmentName": "MyServerName",
    "EndpointAddress": "net.tcp://MyServerName:8201/Services/"
}
```

My configuration binding class is this:

```
public class MyEnvironment
{
    public string EnvironmentName { get; set; }
    public string EndpointAddress { get; set; }
    public string AzureAuthRelayConStr { get; set; }
    public string AzureStorageConnectionStr { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Program.cs`:

```
var MyEnvironment = new MyEnvironment();
builder.Configuration.GetSection(machineName).Bind(MyEnvironment);

// Here is the problem. This doesn't persist. I know I can add this to the constructor, but what's the proper
// method of making changes before binding?
MyEnvironment.AzureStorageConnectionStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");

builder.Services.Configure<MyEnvironment>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(machineName));
```

The second to last line is what I'm trying to solve, but it doesn't persist. I realize I can probably add those other parameters to the constructor, but my question is what's the proper way to modify them before binding or is it possible?

Is there a way to pass a `List` to `IOptions` or just some generic parameters without declaring a custom class with a JSON?

Comment: How are you constructing the `Configuration`? By default it will include environment variables, but you can add your own provider.

Comment: @gunr2171 I just edited the last code block to include how I was doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<MyEnvironment>(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(machineName).Bind(options);

    options.AzureStorageConnectionStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
});
```

Comment: Ah bingo! I see what I was doing wrong.